# Wifi Extender setup issue irrespective of brand name and modal number

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-extender

I have done WiFi Extender Setup of well-known brands and modal numbers.

Irrespective of brand name and modal number, I faced difficulties while extender setup.

In some cases, users do not have computer and some extender doesn’t get easily setup with WPS.
Moreover, in some cases, the main router doesn’t have WPS button.

User is unable to manage a computer and ethernet cable.

In such scenarios, irrespective of brand name and modal number, please let me know how to setup wifi extender with android and iPhone?

With Regards

TekQ

Comment: `irrespective of brand name and modal number` .. In my experience, this varies by brand name and model number so I am wondering how someone can provide you with this information as requested.  Perform a full reset of the device (depending on brand and model).  There will be some SSID that appears on your network (depending on brand and model).  You will connect to some IP (depending on brand and model).  You will login with credentials (depending on brand and model).  You will setup the device with instructions provided by the brand and model.  I am confused.

Comment: I used “irrespective of brand name and modal number”. I did setup Wifi Extender of Linksys, TP-Link & Netgear. Setup steps of almost all are similar except url.

Comment: Issues I explained are not specific to a single modal number. Some modal numbers easily get setup. In some cases, we get stuck.

Comment: For example, in some cases, smartphone or computer doesn’t get connected with extender before setup.
I did Reset. However, it doesn’t get connected but it gets setup easily after connecting with computer using ethernet cable.
In some cases, setup is easier with WPS but is some cases it doesn’t get setup with WPS.
In most cases, Ext is automatically added with extender network. In some cases, Ext is not added automatically with extender network.